# What were earliest attempts to make computers accessible?

Tags: computer-accessibility

Today, you have plenty of options: screen reader, magnifier, on-screen keyboard, etc.

But how was the situation back then?

Were there any options to make it easier for people with disabilities?

Since it's a broad topic, let's say for desktop computers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be really computer related, but rather generic - it might help to narrow this down to areas that are not already covered by generic equipment, specific to computer use and specific to defined use cases. Otherwise this will be way to broad and unspecific. (Also note that this is kind of a chicken and egg issuer, as computers only entered workspace of people with disabilities quite recent and _after_ development of additional tools).

Comment: Yes, edited it to specifically mention desktop computers.

Comment: Still not really changing being as broad, as computers in office use are present since the 1960s. Not to mention that items like braille lines have been attached to mainframe terminals, so predating today's PCs by a decade or more.

Comment: Not sure how to improve it... and basically, you more or less answered the question!

Comment: @Greenonline I think it's still a fitting answer as it does supply several examples that development of accessibility always was present from the very begin.

Comment: Before we had GUIs and multimedia, it was actually much easier to make computers accessible than it is today. A braille reader was practically all you needed, because all computers were limited to text output. And these were available around the mid seventies.

Comment: The very earliest computers used in academia and industry (unfortunately not desktops) were accessible to people with disabilities in theory. That is because the UI is a human. There is usually a place (a department, a room, a window etc.) where you can submit your programs to execute to a person who will tell you in a human language that they'll run your program and you can come back later for the results. At some later time you can come back and pick up your reel of dot-matrix printed paper

Comment: A friend of mine at Stirling Uni wrote a predictive text program for mainframe terminals as his final year project in 1989.

Comment: Back in the 1980s: thick glasses, and sitting *very* close to the monitor.  Worked for at least one guy.  Text mode only, of course.

Comment: "Back Then" is a pretty vague time period.  The situation in the 60's, 70's and 80's were all very different from each other.

Comment: I agree. Back when? And also, "accessible" is a very vague term.  Are you talking about access by people with poor or no sight?  With problematic hand-eye coordination?  With dyslexia or similar disabilities?

Comment: How is an on-screen "key"board more accessible than a real keyboard? The real one has real keys you can feel individually. You can really press them down, and feel it when you do so, giving you tactile feedback that your press worked.

Comment: Answers have been posted, yet question got closed as it lacks details/clarity... Don't know how I can make it any clearer than asking what (hardware, software or whatever else) did help easing access to computers for persons with disabilities? I mean, it's pretty clear... If you think you can improve the question somehow by editing it, then please do so.

Comment: It is just too broad, unfortunately. How would you select which answer is correct? Would you select a rambling answer that tries to cover all bases? Or one that provides the first ever accessibility program or tool? Also, how to define computer? Is it a desktop? But then why discount a terminal for Multics, that provides large text, or TTS, or specialised input device? What about an even earlier "computer" that doesn't have  (what is now considered) a typical UI or VDU? Also as dave points out in his comment, which handicap takes preference? That is when opinions come into play...

Comment: I get your point... I'll pick one that fits best. (not ideal but, as you mentioned, that's life, lol)

Answer (score 12):

Back in the mid 1980s (around 1984-1985), when I was a high school student, I implemented what I believe were some of the first accessibility enhancements for the Apple ][ series. These were designed for people with low vision or (legal, but not complete) blindness.

Bigprint - This changed the display on the Apple ][ from 40x24 characters to 20x12 characters using the high resolution display. This was compatible with Applesoft Basic so you could write and run text mode programs using the larger characters.

Megaword - This was a whole word processor based on the Bigprint display engine. It had formatting commands (troff-like) and supported a wide variety of dot matrix printers. It would print big letters on the page using the printer "graphics" mode.

These were developed in conjunction with a non-profit organisation (which I forget the name of) and I believe some funding came from the Canadian National Institute of the Blind.

I received national recognition for the development of these programs in conjunction with youth sicence fair competitions.

Unfortunately, since this was long before the Internet, I can't find any evidence of these two programs online today. So I only have my own recollection of these programs to present.

Comment: Do you still have the listings, code or floppies?

Comment: @Greenonline: I don't have anything easily accessible to me now, but that stuff may still exist in may parents' basement. I did find a photo of a photo! https://hewgill.com/~greg/IMG_2063.JPG

Comment: Cool. If you manage to get the code/listing you should pop it up on GitHub/Gitlab for posterity. :-)

Answer (score 11):

##### TL;DR

It *sort of* depends on how you define accessibility and computers, but 1808 (typewriter) or 1886 (punchcards), maybe?

Or more compatible with what we *now* call computers: 1964 (TTY), or 1972 (ARPANET). Or anywhere between those dates.

Or mid- to late-1980s for *actual* desktop computers, including the "pre IBM PC" machines.

---

##### A technological timeline(?)

From [history of accessible technology](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/2005-06/accessibility/firstwave.html)

> - 1808 – The first typewriter is built by Pellegrino Turri to help a blind friend write legibly.
> - 1886 – Herman Hollerith, who had a cognitive processing disability, implemented the idea of using punch cards to transport data from the 1890 census. He later founded the Tabulating Machine Company. In 1924, it became known as IBM.
> - 1916 – At Bell Labs, Harvey Fletcher built the Western Electric Model 2A hearing aid.
> - 1934 – The Readphon Talking Book was invented.
> - 1935 – The American Foundation for the Blind publishes the first issue of the Talking Book Bulletin (books on tape).
> - 1936 – Bell Labs invents the first electronic speech synthesizer called “Voder” (for “voice coder”).
> - 1948 – John Bardeed, William Shockley and Walter Brattain at Bell Labs invented the transistor to create more reliable, smaller, cheaper, more efficient hearing aids. They won the 1956 Nobel Prize for Physics.
> - 1960 – Pilgrim Imagine started captioning for the deaf.
> - 1964 – A deaf orthodontist sent a teletype machine to a deaf scientist, beginning the TTY (Teletypewriter) revolution.
> - 1972 - The first national open-captioned program aired on PBS (The French Chef with Julia Child).
> - 1972 – Vinton Cerf, who had a hearing impairment and was married to a deaf woman, developed host level protocols for ARPANET. He communicated with his wife through the computer using text – the precursor to e-mail.
> - 1975 – Ray Kurzweil created the Kurzweil Reading Machine and the first OCR technology and created one of the first CCD (charge coupled device) scanners.
> - 1986 – Jim Thatcher created the first screen reader at IBM, called IBM Screen Reader (for DOS). At first it wasn’t trademarked because it was primarily for low vision staff members. He later created a Screen Reader/2 for graphical interface PCs (4).
> - 1988 - Retail registers began to use picture based keyboards, originally created to help those that couldn’t speak be able to use a synthesizer to talk.
> - 1990 – The Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) is passed. This Act requires “civil rights protections to individuals with disabilities similar to those provided to individuals on the basis of race, color, sex, national origin, age, and religion. It guarantees equal opportunity for individuals with disabilities in public accommodations, employment, transportation, State and local government services, and telecommunications” (17).
> - 1994 – National Federation of the Blind created a synthetic speech newspaper updated daily.
> - 1995 – Microsoft issued Windows 95, the first time their OS had built in accessibility features (rather than as an add-on) (5).
> - 1996 – Productivity Works created pwWebSpeak, a browser that translated text into speech.
> - 1997 – NCR Corp created the first audio ATM, accessible to blind or illiterate users.
> - 1998 – Synchronized Accessible Media Exchange (SAMI) released to allow simplified ability to caption and audio describe videos (5).
> - 1998 – Section 508 is added to the Rehabilitation Act, requiring that government agencies make their websites more accessible to people with disabilities. Some of these requirements include text descriptions of images, elimination of flashing colors, and regulations against changing a user’s preset contrast setting (16).
> - 1999 – World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) released Web Content Accessibility guidelines.
> - 2000 – Microsoft Windows 2000 released, with an on screen keyboard option and the ability to translate text to speech for illiterate or blind users (5).

---

##### Apple Macintosh

From [Happy 40th Birthday to Apple: A Look Back at Apple's Progress](https://www.afb.org/aw/17/6/15322):

> **Accessibility History**
>
> Apple was not always a leader in accessibility. Blind computer users could add the Echo 2 speech synthesizer to their early Apple computers and Apple eventually offered the Outspoken speech synthesizer, but neither synthesizer gave full functionality. Low vision users also did not have many options.
>
> In the mid-90s, Windows computers had better functionality. A third-party screen reader such as Window-Eyes or JAWS was required. These screen readers were expensive but gave better access.
>
> With the launch of OS X 10.2 Jaguar, Apple introduced Universal Access. This software was supposed to improve accessibility greatly for people who are blind, have low vision and have physical limitations. However, it did not work as well as expected.
>
> ...

However, the above article ***drastically** under-sells* the early Macintosh's abilities.

There were a myriad of [extensions](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/system/?c=105&p=1), or control panels (some Apple, others mostly third-party freeware or shareware), for at least System 7.x (7.1-7.5 or thereafter) through to System 9 (and even some earlier system versions), that provided some level of accessibility of the Macintosh.

I can't really find much evidence online, apart from:

- [MacInTalk](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/2590-macintalk), **1985**: Provides text-to-speech functionality:

> MacinTalk is Apple's text-to-speech, or speech synthesizer, extension that allows Mac documents to "talk" their text using a range of computerized voices.
>
> MacinTalk (v1.0.2) was relased on April 15, 1985 and works on Mac OS 1.x to Mac OS 6.x
>
> MacinTalk 2 and MacinTalk Pro (both v1.2) were released in 1994 for Mac OS 6 or 7 and were almost immediately made obsolete by MacinTalk 3.
>
> MacinTalk 3 (v1.4) was released in 1995 and became Apple's TTS standard until OSX and is part of Mac OS 7, 8 and 9.

- [PlainTalk](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/48517-plaintalk-text-to-speech) and [PlainTalk](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/48531-plaintalk), (date?): Provides text-to-speech functionality
- [StickyClick](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/17680-stickyclick): Provides the "sticky" menu action introduced in Mac OS 8 to users of System 7.

> Sticky Click is a hack that adds the best feature of a trackball to the mouse. With a trackball, the mouse buttons can be sticky, that is, when a menu is chosen, the mouse button does not have to remain down to make the menu stay open. This is a short cut that allows the hand to relax and the user to be more productive. Steve Zeller, the author of FinderMenu, created this hack to provide the trackball functionality when using the mouse.

- [Fat Cursors](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/25630-fat-cursors): A system control panel that installs slightly larger Arrow and IBeam cursors
- [FindCursor](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/25631-findcursor): A system extension which enables users to quickly locate the current cursor position visually.
- [Front&Center](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/25632-front-center): A control panel that allows the user to find the cursor location by pressing a hot key.  The cursor flashes (appears and disappears). This accessibility utility is better than other cursor finders, because it does not interfere with the control-click contextual menu, so it can be used under Mac OS 8 and 9, beyond its System 7 scope.
- [Apple Disability Solutions Software](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/7748-apple-disability-solutions-software) which includes a veritable *plethora* of extensions and tools, such as:

  - CloseView, EasyAccess, EnglishSpeech, MAP2.0, MouseKeysPowerBook1.0, 7.5.1_Keyboard_Shortcuts_f, Aaron_s_Dvorak, Adding_Command_Key_Shortcut, ASL_Stack, Audio_Interface_v1.1, AugmentiCom, AutoMenus_Pro, AutoMenus_Pro, B-Ball, Bail_2.0.2, BIGGY, BrailleFonts, Color_Arrow_Folder, CopyPaste_3.3_folder, DI_Dvorak_layouts_1.0.1, DisabilityPics, Dvorak_Modifications, enLARGE, Face_Maker, Fat_Cursors-122-cdev, FinderPop, Freedom, Gallaudet_Font, HyperCard_Player, HyperTyper, IEP_Templates, IIe_3.0, Int_l_Handicapped_Symbol, KBMenu_Enabler_PPC_
    LargePrint, Look_Mom No_Hands__1.5.1, MacinTalk, NiceStopShutDown_1.0.2_Fo-, Object_Functions, Pic_Maker, Say_It, Scan___Calc_Demo, SD_Food_Ordering_boards, SD_house_motif_graphics, SD_Measure_Amount_boards, SerialKeys_Folder, Sign_Finder_Demo_1.1, Snap-To, Speak2Me_1.0_f, Speech_Manager, SpeedyMouseII, T-Minus_Ten_1.0.2, The_Tilery_3.2.1, Typeit4Me, U.S._-_Dvorak, UltraLaunch_1.0, Voice_Box_Folder, and WrapScreen_1.4

##### Windows

- 1988 TRACE: [A Brief History of Microsoft and Accessibility](https://www.afb.org/aw/1/4/16165)

> A few years later, in 1988, the company [Microsoft] added the first accessibility support program for Windows by incorporating work developed at the TRACE Center, a research and development center on accessible technology at the University of Wisconsin. Known then as Access Utility for Windows 2.0, the program improved the accessibility of Windows for people who are deaf, hard of hearing, or who have limited dexterity—by allowing alterations in the use of the keyboard and mouse, providing visual alerts for the computer's sounds, and making it possible to operate the computer through devices hooked to the serial port.

- April 1992: [Windows 3.1x Access Pack](http://aggedor.freeshell.org/w31ap1.html) provided the following features:

> - StickyKeys: allows single-fingered typing
> - SlowKeys:   ignores keys which are pressed accidentally or for a short time
> - RepeatKeys:     adjusts or disables the keyboard repeat rate
> - BounceKeys:      ignores keys which are pressed too quickly or at the same time
> - MouseKeys:  allows control of the mouse cursor using the keyboard
> - ToggleKeys:     provides audio queues when toggle keys are turned on or off
> - SerialKeys:     allows control of the computer using an alternate input device
> - ShowSounds: provides a visual cue when sounds are generated
> - TimeOut:    turns off the Access features when they're not being used

---

##### "Pre IBM PC" computers

From this Adrian's Digital Basement video that I came across last month, [What mysterious retro goodies can we find inside these boxes?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2P53e_liD7k) @ [1:07:35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2P53e_liD7k&t=4055), there is the **ESAM Cognitive Learning Pack**, now known as AAC (Augmentative Alternative Communication), from **1987**:

[image: The C64 and components]

[image: More C64 and components]

[image: Screenshot of ESAM]

Comment: Personally I do not really consider any of the mentioned machines as 'pre-PC' as they are all PCs. Maybe Pre-IBM-PC, but that's a rather random point in time.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of what I meant, thanks. I'll clarify answer (again) :-)

Comment: 1983: [DECtalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECtalk) text-to-speech and various other functions. And the voice of Stephen Hawking.

Comment: @HABO - Good point. You should post that as an answer. An explanation of Hawking's voice should garner a few upvotes.

Comment: TTS and speech synthesizers go way back before Macintalk (which is SAM) or DECtalk. Vortrax synthesizers go back until the early 1970s. [Unix' speak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speak_(Unix) of 1973 was based on their hardware. Between 1980 to 1985 their SC-01 and SC-02 (SSI-263) created a huge speech hype  during those years. Companies produced expansion boards for next to every computer and countless TTS products based on those. Oh, and don't forget TI's Speech Synthesizer for the 99/4

Comment: @Raffzahn - Interesting. I had a [Currah µSpeech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currah), for the Speccy, which was circa 1983 (I think?). However,  *that* seemed more for games, rather than accessibility (although maybe I have that wrong). These speech synthesizers *could* be put in the "timeline section"... but that would mess up the direct block quote. Maybe I'll make a new section, just for speech synths ..?

Comment: @Greenonline I think it already proves the point well enough. Accessibility is neither special not rare, but he whole point of putting a computer on a desk. Thus solutions have always been plenty.

Comment: Why does this history timeline contain zero events outside the USA?

Comment: @gerrit - That is a question for the owner of that particular web page, from whence the quote came... :-)

Comment: 1964: Founding of the Association for Computing Machinery's "Committee on Professional Activities for the Blind", renamed 1971 "Special Interest Group on Computers and the Physically Handicapped", nowadays [SIGACCESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGACCESS).

Answer (score 5):

Creating machine to support human abilities is as old as humanity, no matter if dedicated or made to adapt existing machinery. Whenever some technology became available it would be adapted.

Braille lines may be a good example for this fact. The first working multi character braille line was developed by Klaus Peter Schönherr in 1974. He was awarded German [patent #27 07 3627](https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/pat/register?AKZ=27073627&CURSOR=1) in 1978.

The development happened about the same time computer became an office tool operated by non specialists - right the first time adding a line to a computer (terminal) would be a useful option.

Already before the patent was awarded a Siemens 8150 mainframe terminal was modified in 1976 to operate with the braille line in addition to it's screen. The line could display 12 characters. To move it around the screen 5 cursor keys (direction plus home) was supplied.

**Note:** Accessibility is not something offered as afterthought on good will but a prime requirement for doing business: people with disabilities are customers as well.

Comment: Before refreshable braille displays, there were braille printers and braille typewriters that embossed paper.  They were adapted quite early to be driven by computer - at least by the late 1960s.  One of the programmers of Multics at MIT, Ed Glaser, was blind.